# PDO and Mysql charset

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, character-encoding

I recently switched to PDO for many projects (used mysql/i drivers for too much time to be told) and encountered a strange behavior with the PDO Mysql driver and the charset.
I found out on StackOverflow that THE correct way to intialize a utf8 connection using pdo and mysql is to add `Charset=utf8` at the end of the DSN. Yet this parameter was silently ignored in php version prior to 5.3.6.
Since I'm developing a cms, and I won't know which environment it will run on; I'm searching for a solution to make it compatible.

The first answer I found is use `$PDO->exec("SET NAMES utf8");`
Wouldn't that be the same of issuing a query, so, it would mess up thing with the escape functions.

The second answer is to set `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` to `SET NAMES utf8`, so wouldn't that be the same as before ? (and so break escape functions ?)

Actually I'm getting a bit confused about this, and so I decided to ask for help. I've also thought of two solutions:

1) Build an abstraction layer and in case of PHP < 5.3.6 use mysqli driver instead

2) Utilize another charset and encode/decode each time the data are passed through the socket

Thanks

Comment: not sure what you mean by "mess up thing with the escape functions". There's nothing in that query that'd need escaping.

Comment: Using `SET NAMES utf8` as explained in [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php) would not affect the escape functions like `mysql(i)_real_escape_string()` or `PDO::quote()`

Comment: You shouldn't be using manual quoting anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't bother.

As a matter of fact, `utf-8` use **exactly** the same escaping rules as default `latin1`.

So, it wouldn't mess up thing with the escape functions. Not to mention that you shouldn't use them manually at all (though they are used silently in emulation mode).

As long as you are using utf-8 for your sites, just keep `charset` in DSN and put `$PDO->exec("SET NAMES utf8");` for compatibility and you will have all the possible cases covered.

Another thing on "messing with escape functions" is that you can turn **emulation mode** off, and thus, as long as you are using **placeholders** to represent your data in the query,

```
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

[**no escaping would be involved ever.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265319/285587) - so, there would be no point to worry at all.

Comment: Wouldn't that however expose me to injections ? (also I won't use them directly of course)

Comment: I wouldn't write my answer if it would. utf-8 is as invulnerable as latin1. That's the point.

Comment: By the way "just in case", do you happen to know how other popular CMSs handle this kind of things ? For example, do they all use utf8 or do they let the administrator decide at install-time ?

Comment: No, I don't quite know. I think most of them don't care at all.